# How to write a smart contract that transfers funds from an address in the future

Tags: contract-development, contract-invocation, smart-contract-wallets

Following understanding that smart contracts do not have private keys and cannot sign transactions I am wondering how would a smart contract that transfers funds from an address in the future look like.

Imagine a scenario where an address receives some funds, and after a week, the fund should be returned automatically. That is, the contract should not count on the address that has the funds to return it.

In such a scenario, how can the smart contract initiate the transaction that returns the fund?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your question is about making a scheduled execution functionality on the smart contract? I don't think it's possible currently. execution must be initiated by an account whether a smart contract or a user account with ether

Answer (score 2):

You cannot set up cron jobs in Solidity. Actually, Ethereum as a whole does not natively support this kind of operation.

You have to use an automation protocol that runs on top of Ethereum, e.g. [Gelato Network](https://www.gelato.network/).